# js regular expression match between two sets of delimiters, that might occur many times

Tags: javascript, regex

am trying to retrieve data that exists between two different delimiters,

where this pattern might occur multiple times this is my regular expression so far

`/\@\((\w*)\)\{\{\{([^]*)\}\}\};/`

this works for a single match, and occationaly it will also match the entire set correctly if there is other data between the sets of delimiters, but normally this is not the case
 but in most situations, it will match

for example

```
@(name){{{
contains a bunch of arbitrary text to save for later
when @name occurs again, it will be replaced with this.
}}};
@name
@(broken){{{
  this is a broken match
}}};
```

will normaly capture the pattern

```
contains a bunch of arbitrary text to save for later
when @name occurs again, it will be replaced with this.
}}};
@name
@(broken){{{
  this is a broken match
```

I know that some where I need a non greedy evaluation, but I am not exactly sure where.

I also have the intent of eventualy needing to take this pattern farther, and nest, resulting in structures such as the following:

```
@(name){{{
  @(anotherName){{{
    contains a bunch of arbitrary text to save for later
    when @name occurs again, it will be replaced with this.
  }}}
  @anotherName;
}}};
@name
@(broken){{{
  this is a broken match
}}};
```

though for this I am almost certain I cannot use regular expressions alone, and recursion is beyond the scope of my question, but I would like to be proven wrong though.

## edit:

I had tried the given patterns previously, to no avail, but the accepted answer and the example provided by it proved to me that it could not be a regular expression problem, but rather an issue with the program it's self.

I was looping replacements, because it was possible that one replacement might add a new instance of the string to be replaced, and would require additional expansion. I was setting the test value to true, which would make the loop start over again, and never setting it back to false.

Always a something small.

Comment: `/\@\((\w*)\)\{\{\{([^]*)\}\}\};/` should be `/\@\((\w*)\)\{\{\{([^]*)\}\}\};/g`. The global `g` flag will make it work for multiple matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it non-greedy with adding `?` after `*` and use modifier `g` to make it global :

```
/\@\((\w*)\)\{\{\{([^]*?)\}\}\};/g
```

[see the DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oE0wP4/1).

As you can see it matches the following part separately :

```
@(name){{{
  @(anotherName){{{
    contains a bunch of arbitrary text to save for later
    when @name occurs again, it will be replaced with this.
  }}}
  @anotherName;
}}};
```

and

```
@(broken){{{
  this is a broken match
}}};
```

And it doesn't match nested patters.Its because of that the most of regex engines doesn't support nested matching because in that case you'll fall into [*Context Free Grammers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) and its opposed of *regular languages*

---

So as a proper way for such tasks you can use a appropriate Parser.

Comment: Thank you for that, I have actually tried that same pattern, and it wasn't working. but it turns out I had another mistake in my program.

Comment: @riatzukiza Welcome! yeah as you can see it works in Demo.maybe you have made a mistake already!

Answer (score 1):

Just add `?` after each `*` to use non-greedy matches:

```
/\@\((\w*?)\)\{\{\{([^]*?)\}\}\};/
```

Comment: I had even tried that, there was another bug in my program it seems.